# Is it considered bad practice to create records for two different tables in one controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a has_many through association, almost [exactly like this one from the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and I'm trying to create `events` and link the events to `users` through a table named `appointments`.  The code below (my attempt) seems like a pretty decent solution to the problem of having to update two tables at once, but I'm not 100% confident it is correct since I am creating an event inside the appointments controller and not in the event controller.  Is this ok in cases of table joins or is it viewed as bad practice?

...and if it is considered bad practice, please share an alternative solution if you can.  Thank you.

The class:

`class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController`

The action:

```
def create
  @event = Event.create(appointment_params[:event_id])
  Appointment.create({user_id: @current_user.id, event_id: @event.id})
  redirect_to action: 'index'
end
```

My appointment_params:

```
def appointment_params
  params.require(:appointment).permit(:user_id, event_id: [:id, :location, :time, :subject, :created_at, :updated_at ])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this code needs some refactor, lets do it:

First: you permit a `user_id:` param that is not used at all. Because you are using `@current_user.id`. You can remove this field from the permitted params (and also from the form).

Now, you only need to permit the `event_id:` object. With that name it must be an ID, not a model object. Usually you will see something like `event_attributes` (working with nested attributes). But, if all the data received by the controller is for an Event, then it must be at  `EventsController` and not at `AppointmentsController`. You need to move this action to EventsController.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.users << @current_user
    if @event.save
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:location, :time, :subject)
    end
end
```

I did remove the fields `:id`, `:created_at` and `:updated_at` because they are not needed, and the timestamps are managed by Rails automagic.

With this controller action, a new record at `Appointments` will be added.

Best practices here:

1. Only permit the fields that your user must provide. [more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)
2. Use RESTFul actions, at `EventsController` `create` an `Event`. At routes `resources` keyword create all restful actions: [some example of restful](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Just follow the convention and let Rails do the job.

Comment: This basically solved all of my problems and refactored my code in exactly the way I imagined but was unable to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't bother me, but some won't like it. While the above is fairly simply, what if it gets more complex? What if you then have a need to do this same thing from somewhere else (some background task, via an API, anywhere you might not be hitting the controller action).  That's the primary reason not to do it.

Couple of questions to ask:

- Will you *always* create an Appointment after creating an Event?
- Might you want to do this same thing from somewhere else (ie. console, API, etc.?)

If so, you've got a couple of options depending on how you answer the question.

- If you always do it you could use a callback on Event to create the Appointment. Callbacks are another thing some people don't like, but makes sense here IMHO.
- Define a `create_with_appointment` method on Event and put the logic in there.
- Create a service object to handle it.